# How to maintain the controls state when navigating through asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net-2.0

When we use asp.net pages we can navigate from one page to another via more than one method.

This issue becomes more comlicated when you want to keep the history of current user navigation.

Lets say we have a form. The user will start to fill it, by adding values to one or more fields, but on my case he can create a navigation to another page before we posting-back the current page and thats ofcourse couses the controls to loose its values.

How can i keep the controls states through postbacks between asp.net pages.

Should i use the SessionState or maybe cache it for each user?

thanx

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much have the choice of session state, cookies, or home grown state maintenance using a database.  I typically get around this by combining all my pages into separate panels within a single .aspx.  That way I can use object persistence and viewstate.  Rather than navigating from page to page, I merely have to toggle the .visible property of different panels depending on my users' navigation choices.

RO

Comment: A downside to this approach is the potentially hefty page-weight as your page will contain the viewstate for all items, visible or not.

Comment: This is true... yet another tradeoff.  I've found, however, that performance has been acceptable even with a sizable viewstate.

Answer (score 0):

The answer mostly different in different application types. For example if you plan that your application will have a lot of people storing in session become an expensive operation, but for small applications it work good.
In all cases you can create some mechanism that will store temporary entered data into database, this approach will work everywhere, but it's slowly than in memory cache.
To give correct advice please explain a bit more about your application.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Session variables or the ASP.NET Cache object to store state so that the user can resume filling in the form after navigating away from the page.  However, if the issue is that the data entry is a lengthy process that the user may wish to pause and resume at a later time, give them the option to save their current progress to a database.  If the user attempts to navigate away from the page, remind them that they may lose their current work and give them the option to save it.